# $\iint_{D}(2x-3y)^2dxdy$ over rotated ellipse

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

for the area:

$$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 1\leq 5x^2-8xy+13y^2\leq 4,2x\geq 3y\}$$

I need to solve the double integral:

$$\iint_{D}(2x-3y)^2dxdy$$

I'm adding a sketch of area D (from desmos):
[image: sketch of D area]

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how can I change the variables, $\\$
I've tried regular elliptical variables
change but it doesn't seem to work.

It seems like I have to work on the rotation of the space first, but I don't know how to perform it with the Jacobian.

I would appreciate a general explanation of how to rotate shapes around different axes using Jacobian.

I tried this change of variables but it doesn't seem to help solve the integral:

$$ x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}r\cos(\theta)$$

$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}r\cos(\theta)$$

Comment: Can you show your work with elliptical change of variables?

Comment: @A.P. added to the post

Comment: You'll need to rotate first then squish to a circle. From there, polar coordinates.

Comment: @seanroberson How can I preform the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the ellipse can be rewritten as

$$5x^2-8xy+13y^2 = 4x^2-12xy+9y^2 + x^2+4xy+4y^2 = (2x-3y)^2+(x+2y)^2$$

So use the substitutions

$$\begin{cases}\begin{cases}2x-3y = u \\ x+2y = v\end{cases} \\ \begin{cases}u = r\cos\theta \\ v = r\sin\theta\end{cases}\end{cases} \implies J_{xy\to r\theta} = J_{uv\to xy}^{-1}\cdot J_{uv\to r\theta} = \frac{r}{7}$$

which gives the integral

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_1^2\frac{1}{7}r^3\cos^2\theta\:dr\:d\theta = \frac{15\pi}{56}$$

Comment: thank you! where did you take  $2x\geq 3y$ into consideration?

Comment: $2x-3y \geq 0$ ...care to guess what happens next?

Comment: Ok I get it now, thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{5&-4\\-4&13}\pmatrix{x\\y}\le 4$$

The charactristic equation is $\lambda^2 - 18\lambda + 49 = 0$

The eigenvalues are $9+4\sqrt 2, 9-4\sqrt 2$

The eigenvectors are $\pmatrix{1+\sqrt 2\\1}, \pmatrix{1-\sqrt{2}\\1}$

Which corresponds to a rotation angle of $\frac {\pi}{8}$

$$x = \frac {9-4\sqrt 2}{49}r\cos \left(\theta - \frac {\pi}{8}\right)\\
y = \frac {9+4\sqrt 2}{49}r\sin \left(\theta - \frac {\pi}{8}\right)$$

Comment: thank you, I was not familiar with that method